# A function to copy values to an empty cell on VBA according to some conditions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm a newbie in the programming world and I'm currently facing a challenge on VBA.

I've built a monthly calendar spreadsheet, and below every day number there is an empty space to be filled depending on some conditions.

I want to fill these spaces with a list of names, depending if the person has the value of Active or not. Another imposed condition is if the date of the calendar is a holliday the cell will remain an empty space, therefore I did a list of hollidays to test this condition.

Here goes the code i made so far:

```
Sub teste()
line_fill = 5
line_names = 3
column_names = 17
column_active = 18

For i = 6 To 10
    Dim values As Worksheets("Planilha1").Cells(5, i))
    Dim test As Worksheets("Planilha1").Cells(line_fill - 1, i)
    Dim names As Worksheets("Planilha1").Cells(line_names, column_active)
    Dim active As Worksheets("Planilha1").Cells(line_names, column_names)

    If IsEmpty(test) And test.value <> WorksheetFunction.VLookup(test.value, Sheet1.Range("M4:M100"), 1, False) Then
        If names.value = "Ativo" Then
            values = active
    line_names = line_names + 1
    i = i + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

[Image of the spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXgIU.png)

[Link to the spreadsheet I'm using](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/jn692ss1mb7vvqmmjhoae/Tabela-Calend-rio.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=7y26hdgvhfhg675gdz617jfss)

Comment: Always use `Optin Explicit` If you would have, you would have seen all your `Dim` rows in red and error, as that is not the correct way to declare your variables.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understood what you have said. 
Yes, the Dim's are red. And yet, I don't know if my code makes sense, nor what I should do to make it better.

Comment: Do you have to add all active names to all non holidays days at once? Please post an example

Comment: As @alowflyingpig tried to suggest, add the two words *Option Explicit* at the very top of your code sheet. Then try to run your code. When it breaks on an error, note the error description, press the *Debug* button and look at the highlighted line of code. Your code won't get that far because it will fail to compile. Read up on the "Dim statement" on the Internet. Make sure you read about "VBA" and not some related language of similar name. Correct the syntax in your code so that it compiles. Then deal with each error as you try to run it.

Comment: To help point you in the right direction, you need to declare `line_fill` to `column_active` Hint: These would be of type `Long` or `Integer` (persoanlly I use only `Long`).. Also declare `i` and lastly once you update your code with `Option Explicit` at the very top, declare your 4 items in red correctly.

Comment: Hello @RicardoDiaz! I have added a link to an image of my spreadsheet, it's in portuguese, let me know if you have some questions.

@Variatus and alowflyingpig, thank you for the response. I will look into the Dim statement. I'm learning python and I don't know much about excel, I've only used the most common spreadsheet functions in my life, and never worked on VBA, the things I wrote in this code are based in my python programming logic knowledge, and possibly that is why I couldn't get it to work, but unfortunately this spreadsheet showed up as an urgent task in my work.

Comment: I saw the image but it’s not clear whats the expected result.  Please check my question

Comment: @RicardoDiaz no, I have to add one of the active names to each day that is not a holiday, following an alphabetic order. Ex: 02/02/2020 - Ana, 03/02/2020 - Ana Rita ... 08/02/2020 - Roberto. And then, when the names end, it would restart from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to step through the code with `F8` so you understand what I did and try to adjust it to fit your needs.

**This is the setup I used to code it:**

[image: Sheet setup]

**And this is the code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyValuesInCalendar()

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim calendarRange As Range
    Dim holidaysRange As Range
    Dim teamRange As Range
    Dim evalDayCell As Range

    Dim teamFilteredList As Variant

    Dim holidayLastRow As Long
    Dim teamLastRow As Long

    Dim counter As Long

    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1")

    targetSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    Set calendarRange = targetSheet.Range("D4:J13")

    holidayLastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row

    teamLastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, 16).End(xlUp).Row

    Set holidaysRange = targetSheet.Range("L4:N" & holidayLastRow)

    Set teamRange = targetSheet.Range("P3:Q" & teamLastRow)

    teamFilteredList = GetActiveTeamMembers(teamRange)

     For Each evalDayCell In calendarRange.Cells

        If IsNumeric(evalDayCell.Value) And evalDayCell.Value <> vbNullString Then

            If Not IsHoliday(evalDayCell.Value, holidaysRange) Then

                If counter > UBound(teamFilteredList) Then
                    counter = 1
                Else
                    counter = counter + 1
                End If

                evalDayCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = GetTeamMemberName(counter, teamFilteredList)

            End If

        End If

    Next evalDayCell



End Sub

Private Function IsHoliday(ByVal dayNum As Long, ByVal holidayRange As Range) As Boolean

    Dim evalCell As Range

    For Each evalCell In holidayRange.Columns(1).Cells

        If evalCell.Value = dayNum Then

            IsHoliday = True

        End If

    Next evalCell

End Function

Private Function GetActiveTeamMembers(ByVal teamRange As Range) As Variant

    Dim evalCell As Range

    Dim counter As Long
    Dim tempList() As Variant

    For Each evalCell In teamRange.Columns(1).Cells

        If evalCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Ativo" Then

            ReDim Preserve tempList(counter)

            tempList(counter) = evalCell.Value

            counter = counter + 1

        End If

    Next evalCell

    GetActiveTeamMembers = tempList

End Function

Private Function GetTeamMemberName(ByVal counter As Long, ByVal teamFilteredList As Variant) As String

    GetTeamMemberName = teamFilteredList(counter - 1)

End Function
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi @Ricardo Diaz! Thank you very much for your support.

I've tried your code in my spreadsheet and made the appropriate alterations on the cell values and names to run it. But unfortunately nothing happened. I think it is because in my calendar, I have used the format of dates and not numbers, I'll dig into it and keep you posted.

Comment: you can change in the line `If IsNumeric(evalDayCell.Value) And evalDayCell.Value <> vbNullString Then` `IsNumeric` for `IsDate`

Comment: Hi @Ricardo Diaz! everything worked out for the January month! But when i change the months in my spreadsheet, it doesn't work anymore.. I've added a dropbox link to the spreadsheet I'm using, do you think I could organize the months in the calendar in another way so the code could work better?

Comment: Hi Eduardo. Couple of things: You have to adjust the code because you moved your data location. e.g. `holidayLastRow` is now in column 13 and `teamLastRow` in column 17. Also the `calendarRange` is now `E4:K13`, `holidaysRange` begins now in `M4`and teamRange in `Q3`. Let me know if it's clear.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, yes, I've done this adjustments and everything works fine for January, but if I type on C3 cell the date 01/04/2020 (or any other month) for instance, the code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Check your code against mine: https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArAKssDW3T7wnMBu3TLyK4P1Ym6F0A?e=FX5aGy no problem for me...

Comment: After each date alteration on C3, how do you update the code? Or it changes automatically?

Comment: Code checks the whole range `E4:K13`every time. As you have dates in the calendar, it validates if each one is a holiday then assigns the team member accordingly. is it working for you now?

Comment: Thank you very much for your support and patience! Everything worked great!

Comment: Awesome. please remember to mark the answer so others may find it

Comment: Hello @Ricardo Diaz, can you help me again? My boss asked another function on this spreadsheet. He asked that for each next month, the table pick up the names where it ended the last month and he asked that if the day is a holiday, the values must be cleared on the calendar.

Comment: Hi Eduardo. Please post another question and link it in a comment here. Also, be specific about each requirement (for example what means `each next month` and first give it a try.